# Cant open .dmp file with WinDbg

Tags: windbg, debug-diagnostic-tool

i have problem with opening/loading a dmp.file.
At first, maybe its trivial, but its my first time what i doing creating/analysing of dump file.

File was created on Windows Server 2022 Standard via debug diagnostic tool. I detected a memory leak and i created a full dump file from processes. Its our service, which is coded on .Net TargetFrameworkVersion 4.7.2. But im unable to do analyse with this tool because of some incompatibility. So i searching others possibilities

The files have 3-7gb.
When i tried to open a dmp file i get this error via windbg app on my PC OS windows 10 Enterprise

```
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
   ExtensionRepository : Implicit
   UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : true
   AllowNugetExeUpdate : true
   AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : true
   AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

   -- Configuring repositories
      ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
      ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.000 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.016 seconds
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 36

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.25921.1001 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\user\Desktop\Memory leak\Service.exe__PID__9660__Date__11_14_2023__Time_11_35_35AM__977__Manual Dump.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Comment: 'Dump created by Debug Diagnostic Service. Manual Dump | Process Snapshot API Use Enabled'

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       .sympath srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: .sympath srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 20348 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 20348.1.amd64fre.fe_release.210507-1500
Debug session time: Sat Nov 18 11:35:36.000 2023 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 96 days 0:22:58.543
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:15:06.000
ERROR: Reload failure, partially initialized target
```

I had issued with a symbol path. I use these two paths

```
.sympath srv*c:\localsymbols*https://symbols.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Packages
.sympath srv*c:\localsymbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

[image]
Sometimes occurs the popup when the path is not avaliable, on both cases. Sometimes its seems load but i still getting ERROR: Reload failure, partially initialized target.

Maybe a ask really bad on google and chatgpt, and i missing some essential point.

Comment: For memory related issues, a memory profiler is far better an option to go. If this is your first time to use WinDbg and you want the issue to be resolved as quick as possble, please open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com and share the dumps with Microsoft, as the learning curve is steep.

Comment: You can't use `.sympath` twice. It will overwrite the older setting. Instead, use `.sympath+` to add another symbol path.

Comment: Besides the "ERROR: Reload failure, partially initialized target", are there any commands you want to use and do they produce errors, too? Can you load the dump into other memory analysis tools, e.g. JetBrains dotMemory?